# Using Unmanaged<AnyObject>! as key in NSMutableDictionary

Tags: swift, keychain

I'm trying to create a keychain query but I'm having difficulties with using Attribute Item Keys as dictionary keys. When creating the dictionary I can pass the attribute items wrapped in an array as dictionary keys like so without any issues

```
genericPasswordQuery = NSMutableDictionary(objects: [kSecClassGenericPassword, identifier], forKeys: [kSecClass, kSecAttrGeneric])
```

However if I try to add another similar item to the query dict like so:

```
genericPasswordQuery.setObject(accessGroup, key:kSecAttrAccessGroup)
```

It complains that the key doesn't conform to NSCopying and supplies the type error:

"could not find an overload for 'setObject' that accepts the supplied arguments"

This is the standard implementation of a SecItemAdd but I'm having issues doing it in Swift.

Comment: How is `kSecAttrAccessGroup` defined?

Comment: is it necessary using a NSMutableDictionay? Could your code work with a Swift dictionary too? You would have the advantage that your key need not been NSCopying compliant.

Comment: @Areal-17 Using a swift dictionary, I get the error 'could not convert from Dictionary to DictionaryLiteralConvertible'

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think I figured out a solution. From the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/buildingcocoaapps/WorkingWithCocoaDataTypes.html):

> When Swift imports APIs that have not been annotated, the compiler
>   cannot automatically memory manage the returned Core Foundation
>   objects. Swift wraps these returned Core Foundation objects in an
>   Unmanaged structure. All indirectly returned Core Foundation
>   objects are unmanaged as well.
>
> When you receive an unmanaged object from an unannotated API, you
>   should immediately convert it to a memory managed object before you
>   work with it. That way, Swift can handle memory management for you.
>   The Unmanaged structure provides two methods to convert an
>   unmanaged object to a memory managed object—takeUnretainedValue() and
>   takeRetainedValue().

Current implementation:

```
genericPasswordQuery = NSMutableDictionary(objects: [kSecClassGenericPassword, identifier], forKeys: [kSecClass, kSecAttrGeneric])

var kSecAttrAccessGroupSwift: NSString = kSecAttrAccessGroup.takeRetainedValue() as NSString
genericPasswordQuery.setObject(accessGroup, forKey: kSecAttrAccessGroupSwift)
```

This runs fine in Xcode but a Playground immediately crashes when I add .takeRetainedValue